# Find the sids of suppliers who supply only red parts

Tags: sql, db2

again a sql question.

First thing i do is to join the Tables:
Select SID from cat c JOIN part p ON c.PID=p.PID;
I tried the having clause but i have no aggregate function and using a 'where' is useless because then i get all suppliers which supply a red part.

Is there a generalized answer ? so that i can get also the supplier which provides only green parts ?

The output needed:

```
SID   
-----   
S2
```

The Tables provided:

```
SELECT * FROM parts 

PID   PNAME      COLOR      WEIGHT CITY       
----- ---------- ---------- ------ ---------- 
P1    Nut        red            13 London     
P2    Bolt       black          18 Paris      
P3    Screw      red            17 Rome       
P4    Screw      silver         14 London     
P5    Cam        trans          12 Paris      
P6    Cog        cyan           19 London     
P7    Nut        magenta        15 -          
P8    Wheel      red            15 Munich     
P9    Bearing    green          15 Milano     

  9 record(s) selected. 


SELECT * FROM catalog 

SID   PID   COST         
----- ----- ------------ 
S1    P3            0.50 
S1    P4            0.50 
S1    P8           11.70 
S2    P1           16.50 
S2    P3            0.55 
S2    P8            7.95 
S3    P8           12.50 
S3    P9            1.00 
S4    P5            2.20 
S4    P6      1247548.23 
S4    P7      1247548.23 

  11 record(s) selected.
```

Thank you for your great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do want aggregation.  One method is to compare the colors using `min()` and `max()`:

```
select c.SID
from cat c JOIN
     part p
     ON c.PID = p.PID
group by c.SID
having min(p.color) = max(p.color) and  -- all colors are the same
       min(p.color) = 'red'             -- and that color is 'red'
```

Comment: what would be the output of min(p.color) and max(p.color) ?

Comment: I dont understand because colors are no numbers. I used min and max only to get the lowest or highest value until now

Comment: @headacheFromCoding . .  `min()` and `max()` work on strings and dates too.

Comment: okay but what would the output look like ? what is the output of max(p.color) that i can understand ?

Comment: @headacheFromCoding . . . It generally uses alphabetic sorting to determining the extreme values.  More specifically, these depend on the particular collation defined for the column, table, or database.